# Button Press Starts Slideshow in Android

Tags: android, slideshow

I want to add images Slideshow functionality in my Audio player app. I got some code for slideshow and that works fine in separate project but when I merge this with my existing code its not working. Can anybody help me How can I make this when play button press images slide show start and when pause button press slide show pause.here i post both codes separately. now help me to merge this with my code Accurately.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.hareemaudio;

import com.example.hareemaudio.R;
import com.example.hareemaudio.SpinersActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    SeekBar seek_bar;
    ImageButton play_button, pause_button, more_button;
    MediaPlayer player;
    TextView text_shown;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

    /** For Pic Slidshow. */
     public int currentimageindex=0;
        Timer timer;
        TimerTask task;
        ImageView slidingimage;

        int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.mic, R.drawable.mic5, R.drawable.mic6,
                R.drawable.more7};


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        getInit();
        seekUpdation();
        addListenerOnButton();


    public void getInit() {
        seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.audioProgressBar);
        play_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        pause_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fatiha); //Audio file that is payng
        seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());

    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    // Button press (more) to change the screen(spinners ajaege)

        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            final Context context = this;

            more_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.more_button);

            more_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpinersActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);   

                }

            });

        }

    public void seekUpdation() {

        seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:




            player.start(); // Start playing Audio
            break;
        case R.id.pause_button:
            player.pause();  //Pause Audio

        }

    }
}
```

CODE FOR SLIDE SHOW:

```
/** For Images Slidshow. */
     public int currentimageindex=0;
        Timer timer;
        TimerTask task;
        ImageView slidingimage;

        int[] IMAGE_IDS = {R.drawable.mic, R.drawable.mic5, R.drawable.mic6,
                R.drawable.mice7};



        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow();

            }
        };

        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 8000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

             mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

        }

        }, delay, period);

    }


       private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

        slidingimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_id);
        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex%IMAGE_IDS.length]);

        currentimageindex++;

      }
//code of slideshow ends here
```

**LOgCat:**

```
09-23 17:03:00.758: D/dalvikvm(1397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 72K, 5% free 2916K/3064K, paused 60ms, total 66ms
09-23 17:03:01.628: I/dalvikvm-heap(1397): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.510MB for 6912016-byte allocation
09-23 17:03:01.688: D/dalvikvm(1397): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 9662K/9816K, paused 55ms, total 55ms
09-23 17:03:03.058: E/MediaPlayer(1397): Should have subtitle controller already set
09-23 17:03:03.508: D/gralloc_goldfish(1397): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 17:03:04.068: D/AndroidRuntime(1397): Shutting down VM
09-23 17:03:04.068: W/dalvikvm(1397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a67b90)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): Process: com.example.hareemaudio, PID: 1397
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.AnimateandSlideShow(MainActivity.java:97)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:94)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:70)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-23 17:03:04.078: E/AndroidRuntime(1397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 17:03:13.038: I/Process(1397): Sending signal. PID: 1397 SIG: 9
09-23 17:04:21.468: D/dalvikvm(1459): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 5% free 2916K/3068K, paused 63ms, total 68ms
09-23 17:04:21.568: I/dalvikvm-heap(1459): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.510MB for 6912016-byte allocation
09-23 17:04:21.638: D/dalvikvm(1459): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 9662K/9820K, paused 63ms, total 63ms
09-23 17:04:22.878: E/MediaPlayer(1459): Should have subtitle controller already set
09-23 17:04:23.348: D/gralloc_goldfish(1459): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 17:04:23.828: D/AndroidRuntime(1459): Shutting down VM
09-23 17:04:23.828: W/dalvikvm(1459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a67b90)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): Process: com.example.hareemaudio, PID: 1459
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.AnimateandSlideShow(MainActivity.java:97)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:94)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:70)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-23 17:04:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1459):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 17:04:29.408: I/Process(1459): Sending signal. PID: 1459 SIG: 9
09-23 17:04:36.198: D/dalvikvm(1483): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 4% free 2916K/3032K, paused 68ms, total 74ms
09-23 17:04:36.308: I/dalvikvm-heap(1483): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.510MB for 6912016-byte allocation
09-23 17:04:36.378: D/dalvikvm(1483): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 2% free 9662K/9784K, paused 61ms, total 61ms
09-23 17:04:37.588: E/MediaPlayer(1483): Should have subtitle controller already set
09-23 17:04:38.098: D/gralloc_goldfish(1483): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-23 17:04:38.498: D/AndroidRuntime(1483): Shutting down VM
09-23 17:04:38.498: W/dalvikvm(1483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a67b90)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): Process: com.example.hareemaudio, PID: 1483
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.AnimateandSlideShow(MainActivity.java:97)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:94)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at com.example.hareemaudio.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:70)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-23 17:04:38.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? Where exactly are you getting them? Please be specific

Comment: @nem App is crashing.plz have a look at my edited Question.i post logCat

Comment: Im not sure if its a pasting error but you are missing a "}"on the OnCreateMethod

Comment: There is a `NullPointerException` in `MainActivity.java` line 97. What is written in the line ?